# Power on laptop when a/c power is switched on?

Tags: boot, power-management, macintosh

i have a 2006 Macbook running xubuntu and i want to use it as a backup server which i want to store in a cupboard. My plan is to use a remote controled power socket to switch it on. What things need to be configured in the system to boot up when the power supply is switched on?
I am not interested in Wake-on-LAN or hibernate etc. Any hint?

Background Info: I want the macbook to act as NAS for my backup and i do not want to keep it away from the network with internet access. Therefore the macbook should start a WLAN hotspot once it is started to let my other computer use it as backup server but only when i want to use it. Power on Lan is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar with the Mac BIOS, traditional PC bioses have an option "Power on AC"

[image: UEFI Bios AC Option]